# JavaScript: Library suitable for creating custom "hotspots" on a image

Tags: javascript, imagemap

I am searching for a open source JavaScript library/plug-in that would allow me to implement a custom function that:

- lets a privileged user place one or more graphical icon (e.g., Google-like pin) anywhere on an image and associate a hyperlink, comments, or other attributes to that object (attributes preferably stored in JSON format)
- lets normal users view those "hotspots" placed by the above privileged user and be able to interact (e.g., hover for more info, click to go to the associated URL, etc) with those objects
- lets the privileged user modify the placement and/or the attributes associated to the icons

I did find a few similar questions in SO but none of them had enough similarities to be the solution I'm looking for. Any pointers will be much appreciated!

Comment: If it's okay for you to use svg objects, then you could do something like this; http://jsfiddle.net/Fizk/qACK4/
It is only a raw sketch, but with some work it could be what you're looking for :)

Comment: @Esben - the demo doesn't appear to be particularly suitable for my need but I could perhaps make a use of your implementation later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [DropPin](https://github.com/duncanheron/dropPin). It could be what you need, though you might need to take care of the user privileges part of it.

Comment: This is the closest to my ideal solution, although I will probably add  a bit more functionality to it. But it's a start. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could look at how [H5P](https://h5p.org) has created an image hotspot content type:
https://h5p.org/image-hotspots

H5P is an open source project, so you may use this as is, or reuse the code found here:
https://github.com/h5p/h5p-image-hotspots

Btw, I am one of the developers contributing to H5P!